# windows form keyup event is not working c#

Tags: c#, .net

This code is not working in my main form

```
void main_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed");


             e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Overriding `ProcessCmdKey` is probably a better option than setting `KeyPreview`.

Comment: _"This code is not working"_ is hardly a good explanation for a problem.  [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Try to set Form property: `main.KeyPreview = true;`

Comment: thanks its working

Comment: Glad to help :)